# How can I make a function wait for another function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this function:

```js
const submitImport = async (value) => {
  const { actions, navigation, account } = this.props;

  this.setState({ isImporting: true });
  actions.importWallet(value.mnemonicPhrase, value.password, 1);
  console.log('acc', account);
  actions.showNotification({
    message: 'Account has been successfully Imported',
    isError: false,
  });
};
```

`importWallet` is adding new properties to `account` object but when I call this function the first time the `account` object is empty but when I click it the second time it is okay. So my guess is  `importWallet` needs time to finish and return the value. I tried to use `async` `await` but it did not work. Also, I tried to use `return new Promise` but it still did not work. Maybe I did it the wrong way idk.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue please?

Comment: Can you please share the code inside `importWallet` ? Also, can you mention where the `submitImport` method is being called ?

Comment: you need to find why it works the second time and not the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the `importWallet` function induces some change in the `account` prop.

All prop changes require atleast one render cycle for the updated values to get visible as `state/prop` changes are asynchronous in react. In your case you are trying to access `account` as soon invoking `actions.importWallet`. Hence as it is within the same render, it has not yet been updated. But as you mentioned, it will be available from the subsequent renders.

Also you cannot make it synchronous with async-await / promises as the asynchronous nature of react state updates is not exposed.

Your usecase may be achieved by some refractor :

1. Try obtaining the new value of account in the return statement of `account.importWallet`. That way you can use it even before the prop updates.

   const updatedAccount = actions.importWallet(value.mnemonicPhrase, value.password, 1);
2. In case you are using React Hooks, you can create an effect with `useEffect` and add `account` as a dependency. This will invoke the effect when the dependency value changes (dependency should be a primitive data type for consistent effect invocation).